# Min/Max number of inequalities needed to determine the order of $n$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, algorithms, information-theory

We are given an ordered $n$-tuple of positive real numbers $R=(r_1,..r_n)$. A $k$-inequality is an inequality of the form

$x_1<x_2<...<x_k$

where $x_1,..,x_k$ are in $R$. For example, for $n=7$, we might have the $3$-inequality $r_5<r_2<r_1$. We would like to order by magnitude all the elements in $R$ given some number of $k$-inequalities.

(1) Find the minimum number of $k$-inequalities such that the ordering is determined.

(2) Find the maximum number of $k$-inequalities one can give such that the ordering is not determined.

---

I made up this problem yesterday, but I'm guessing that this is a well known thing in computer science/information theory/algorithms.

Comment: The first part is easy. For the second part, my approach: let the answer be $f(k,n)$. Use recursion to relate $f(k,n)$ to $f(k,n+1)$. For example take $k=3$. We first give all the $f(3,n)+1$ inequalities not involving $r_{n+1}$ which determine the order of $r_1,..,r_n$, then we need to give inequalities involving $r_{n+1}$. If $r_1,..,r_{n+1}$ are ordered as $x_1<..<x_{n+1}$ with $r_{n+1}=x_k$, then we can give all the inequalities of the form $x_i<x_j<x_k$ with $1 \le i<j<k$ and similarly all of the form $x_k<x_i<x_j$ with $k+1<i<j \le n+1$.

Comment: Also we can give all of the form $x_j<x_k<x_i$ with $1 \le j < k-1$ and $k+1<i\le n$. Its easy to find the number of inequalities that is in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $r_1<r_2<\ldots<r_{n-1}<r_n$.

For $k=2$, the answers are (1) $n-1$ and (2) $\binom{n}2-1$.

In the first case, we can write $r_1<r_2,\ r_2<r_3,\ \ldots,\ r_{n-1}<r_n$.

In the second case, we can write all possible inequalities with $r_1$ as the lesser: $r_1<r_2,\ r_1<r_3,\ \ldots,\ r_1<r_n$ and then all the inequalities with $r_2$ as the lesser, etc., until we reach $r_{n-1}<r_n$, without which the order is not totally decided.

For $k=3$, in the first case we can write $r_1<r_2<r_3$, then $r_3<r_4<r_5$, etc. and establish the order in just $\lceil \tfrac12(n-1)\rceil$ statements.

In the second case, I suspect the answer is $\tbinom{n}3-(n-2)$. Write down all the 3-inequalities except for those which end $\ldots<r_{n-1}<r_n$.

For general $k$, the analogous answers would be (1) $\lceil \tfrac{n-1}{k-1}\rceil$ and (2) $\binom{n}k-\binom{n-2}{k-2}$.

Comment: This looks correct.